# Read text file to an int array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, file, text, nullpointerexception

Given a text file as follow : 
10
100
99
99
96
96
92
92
91
88
87
86

Where the first number **"10"** means that the text file is containing **10** integer and the second number **100** means that all the numbers in the text file doesn't exceed **100**.
My objective is to read the text and fill an `int data[][];` as follow :

```
data[0][0]=1    data[0][1]=99
data[1][0]=2    data[1][1]=99
data[2][0]=3    data[2][1]=96
data[3][0]=4    data[3][1]=96
data[4][0]=5    data[4][1]=92
data[5][0]=6    data[5][1]=92
data[6][0]=7    data[6][1]=91
data[7][0]=8    data[7][1]=88
data[8][0]=9    data[8][1]=87
data[9][0]=10   data[9][1]=86
cbin = 100 // bin capacity 
nbin = 10 // number of objects
```

That's means first raw for index and second for item's value or weights .. and `int cbin = \\the second text's value` and `int nbin = \\the first text's value` 
the problem that i get an Exception in thread

> "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Here is my code :

```
 public static int[][] data=null; \\ in the first of the document

       JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
File f= chooser.getSelectedFile();

        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(interface1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
        int i=0,j=0;
        while (line != null) {

            if(i==0){
                nbin= (int) Integer.parseInt(""+line);
                System.out.println(nbin);
            }
            else if (i==1) {
                cbin=(int) Integer.parseInt(""+line);
                System.out.println(cbin);
            }
          //  sb.append(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        if(i >= 2 && line != null){

               data[j][1]=(int) Integer.parseInt(line);
               data[j][0]=j;
               j++;

             }

            i++;

        }
          }   catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(interface1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(interface1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

Any ideas ??

Comment: Where are you using awt here?

Comment: I have an idea: read the stack trace of your exception (which you haven't posted), see in which line it occurs, and then find out how any variable can be null on that line.

Comment: @hexafraction am using java swing and the algorithm already print for me the `nbin` and `cbin` correctly then it stop. Besides the `f` file refer to the text i mentioned above .

Comment: are you actually initializing you array somewhere?

Comment: @Gianmarco yes of course i already edited the code and mentioned it

Comment: code indentantion will help us and you to understand the code properly.. also try to don't use, you have a lot of `continue` thats a sign of bad algorithm design

Comment: @GhassenBellagha Although not solving your current issue, the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class would probably help make this easier.

Comment: also if you learn to read your stacktrace it says in what line do you have the null pointer exception.

Comment: You are getting `NPE` probably  because `public static int[][] data=null;` You need to initialized this `data` instance before using it. Have you initialized that somewhere else?

Comment: what's with all the `<br>`s?

Comment: @nachokk the stacktrace tells me that the null pointer exception is at the first line when i start filling my table ! and when i printed the `(int) Integer.parseInt(line);` i remarked that it give me `int null int null ...`

Comment: @Doorknob just taping mistake i ve fixed it ..

Comment: Wait, why are you casting the return values of `parseInt` to `int`? It already returns an `int`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), statements such as `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`, `while (scanner.hasNext()) { /* ... */ }`, and `int n = scanner.nextInt();` will make it a much simpler program.

Like so:

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Read {
  public static void main (String [] args) {
    try (
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    ) {
      int nbin = scanner.nextInt();
      int cbin = scanner.nextInt();
      int data[][] = new int[nbin][2];
      for (int i = 0; i < nbin; ++i) {
        data[i][0] = i + 1;
        data[i][1] = scanner.nextInt();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As you said @Gianmarco we need to `initialize` the array before filling it !! so am editing your code @no_answer_not_upvoted and then it works !! thnx for the help guys and in fact using `scanner` is so much better and easier

Comment: you inverted the data :p `data[i][0] = i+1;`
        `data[i][1] = scanner.nextInt();`

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing the array!!

```
public static int[][] data=null;
```

This is not properly initializing, you are "declaring" the variable. That's the same as:

```
public static int[][] data;
```

No differences.

If you want o be able to add something in your array you have to initialize it:

This is the example:

```
public static int[][] data;
try{
    data[1][1] = 5;
    System.out.println("Added");
}catch(NullPointerException e){
    System.out.println("First exception catched");
}
data = new int[10][10];
try{
    data[1][1] = 5;
    System.out.println("added at the second try");
}catch(NullPointerException e){
    System.out.println("Second Exception catched");
}
```

this code will give as result:

```
First exception catched
added at the second try
```

I how you understood why